# Problem in creating a Yaml pipeline in azure Devops

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

[these are the error that I can't fix image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUPq2.png)

```
  trigger:
    - master
schedules:
    - cron: "0 17 * * * 6"
      displayName: ogni giorno alle 17
      branches:
        include: 
        - master
      always: false
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
parameters:
   RestoreBuildProjects: '**/*.csproj'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
      version: 5.0.x
      performMultiLevelLookup: true
   
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    vstsFeed:'f52d4c22-658b-47a0-a62f-134d5435cc85'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '-c Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'
```

**I created this pipeline for an API ASP.NET Core based on the restful model but I can't make it work, as I try to run it it breaks, I've looked for the errors that Azuredevops gave me but I can't for any reason fix them. see attached email. Hope someone can help me. this is my first approach with YAML pipelines as I used to make them with the graphic tool integrated in Azure DevOPs.**

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Comment: Sorry. I checked it only yesterday. Yeah you manage to solve it. Thank you. And sorry for late response 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have helped to modify your yaml file and it shows no error on my test. Here is the yaml:

```
parameters:
  - name: RestoreBuildProjects
    type: string
    default: '**/*.csproj'

trigger:
  - master

schedules:
  - cron: "0 17 * * * 6"
    displayName: ogni giorno alle 17
    branches:
      include: 
      - master
    always: false
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'


steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '5.0.X'
    performMultiLevelLookup: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    # vstsFeed:'f52d4c22-658b-47a0-a62f-134d5435cc85'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '-c Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'myWebsiteName'
```

And please follow this step to use the yaml:

1. Create a new pipeline with the yaml edit.
2. Select the 'Starter Pipeline', this will help you create a new yaml file.
3. Copy the script to the pipeline.
4. **Click the 'settings' on your restore task and select the feed you want to use. Then click the Add button. This step will help you input the full feed ID.**
   [image]

Comment: thank you. i'll try to do it. Previously I used to create a pipeline then selecting a yaml configuration file from my azure repository and try to run my pipeline